# Detached pthread data race from helgrind

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, race-condition

I have a much larger piece of multithreaded software (proprietary and cannot share) which is reporting a data race from helgrind (see data race below). I cannot share this software but I have devised some tests to demonstrate the race.

The race from the actual software having issues:

```
==7746== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0xAC83697 by thread #4
==7746== Locks held: 2, at addresses 0x583BCD8 0x5846F58
==7746==    at 0x4C3A3CC: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7746==    by 0x401375F: _dl_allocate_tls_init (dl-tls.c:515)
==7746==    by 0x5053CED: get_cached_stack (allocatestack.c:254)
==7746==    by 0x5053CED: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:501)
==7746==    by 0x5053CED: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:539)
==7746==    by 0x4C34BB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7746==    by 0x40BFA6: <redacted symbol names from private project>
==7746==    by 0x4C34DB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7746==    by 0x50536B9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==7746== 
==7746== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #10
==7746== Locks held: none
==7746==    at 0x5053622: start_thread (pthread_create.c:265)
==7746==  Address 0xac83697 is in a rw- anonymous segment
==7746==
```

This data race comes up when the software shuts down a series of threads and then re-launches some new threads in the same thread pool. Unfortunately I cannot provide any of this code, however, I believe I was able to reproduce several examples that demonstrate the problem.

---

I've found 3 other questions which relate to this problem:

1. [Why does this recursive pthread_create call result in data race?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560834/why-does-this-recursive-pthread-create-call-result-in-data-race)

The answer to the above was to manually set/allocate the stack, I don't believe this is a viable answer, and if it is, can somebody explain why?

2. [Data race during nested thread creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113375/data-race-during-nested-thread-creation)

The answer didn't have any effect

3. [Data race with detached pthread detected by valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674043/data-race-with-detached-pthread-detected-by-valgrind)

There was no answer to this one.

---

**EDIT:** I have added another (less complex) example at the bottom of this post which can also reproduce the problem.

I was able to rewrite the example given in the first question into a minimally reproducible example, well, mostly.

The following piece of code will generate the following data race about 85% of the time it is run on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

Run with:

```
gcc -g ./test.c -o test -lpthread && valgrind --tool=helgrind ./test
```

```
==15656== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x5C27697 by thread #4
==15656== Locks held: none
==15656==    at 0x4C3A3CC: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==15656==    by 0x401375F: _dl_allocate_tls_init (dl-tls.c:515)
==15656==    by 0x4E47CED: get_cached_stack (allocatestack.c:254)
==15656==    by 0x4E47CED: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:501)
==15656==    by 0x4E47CED: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:539)
==15656==    by 0x4C34BB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==15656==    by 0x400832: launch (test3.c:22)
==15656==    by 0x4008FC: threadfn3 (test3.c:48)
==15656==    by 0x4C34DB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==15656==    by 0x4E476B9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==15656== 
==15656== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==15656== Locks held: none
==15656==    at 0x4E47622: start_thread (pthread_create.c:265)
==15656==  Address 0x5c27697 is in a rw- anonymous segment
```

---

**EDIT:** I have added another (less complex) example at the bottom of this post which can also reproduce the problem.

Here is the program which I have constructed to reproduce the problem, the semaphores are **not necessary** but they seem to greatly increase the chance of the data race occurring.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_t t1;
pthread_t t2;
pthread_t t3;
pthread_t t4;

void *threadfn1(void *p);
void *threadfn2(void *p);
void *threadfn3(void *p);
void *threadfn4(void *p);

sem_t sem;
sem_t sem2;
sem_t sem3;

void launch(pthread_t *t, void *(*fn)(void *), void *arg)
{
    pthread_create(t,NULL,fn,arg);
    pthread_detach(*t);
}

void *threadfn1(void *p)
{
    launch(&t2, threadfn2, NULL);
    printf("1 %p\n", p);
    // notify threadfn3 we are done
    sem_post(&sem);
    return NULL;
}

void *threadfn2(void *p)
{
    launch(&t3, threadfn3, NULL);
    printf("2 %p\n", p);
    // notify threadfn4 we are done
    sem_post(&sem2);
    return NULL;
}

void *threadfn3(void *p)
{
    // wait for threadfn1 to finish
    sem_wait(&sem);
    launch(&t4, threadfn4, NULL);
    // wait for threadfn4 to finish
    sem_wait(&sem3);
    printf("3 %p\n", p);
    return NULL;
}

void *threadfn4(void *p)
{
    // wait for threadfn2 to finish
    sem_wait(&sem2);
    printf("4 %p\n", p);
    // notify threadfn3 we are done
    sem_post(&sem3);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem3, 0, 0);

    launch(&t1, threadfn1, NULL);
    printf("main\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

It appears to be related to threads ending before their parents or parents-of-parents have ended... Ultimately I cannot track down exactly what is causing the data race to occur.

Also it should be noted there is another data race which has come up a few times during my testing, ultimately I was not able to reliably reproduce it because it just appeared on occasion for no reason. The data race was the same as the one I listed, except for the conflict which appeared to list more of a stack trace than just "start_thread", it looked exactly like the data race reported in the first question above except for the bottom where it lists __libc_thread_freeres:

```
==15973== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x5C27697 by thread #4
==15973== Locks held: none
==15973==    at 0x4C3A3CC: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==15973==    by 0x401375F: _dl_allocate_tls_init (dl-tls.c:515)
==15973==    by 0x4E47CED: get_cached_stack (allocatestack.c:254)
==15973==    by 0x4E47CED: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:501)
==15973==    by 0x4E47CED: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:539)
==15973==    by 0x4C34BB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==15973==    by 0x400832: launch (test3.c:22)
==15973==    by 0x4008FC: threadfn3 (test3.c:48)
==15973==    by 0x4C34DB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==15973==    by 0x4E476B9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==15973== 
==15973== This conflicts with a previous read of size 1 by thread #2
==15973== Locks held: none
==15973==    at 0x51C10B1: res_thread_freeres (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so)
==15973==    by 0x51C1061: __libc_thread_freeres (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so)
==15973==    by 0x4E45199: start_thread (pthread_create.c:329)
==15973==    by 0x515547C: clone (clone.S:111)
```

**No, I cannot join the threads, that would not work for our software exhibiting the problem**

**UPDATE**: I have been doing some testing and have managed to generate another example which causes the problem with much less code. If you simply launch threads and detach them in a loop it causes the data race.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// seems we only need 3 threads to cause the problem
#define NUM_THREADS 3

pthread_t t1[NUM_THREADS] = {0};

void launch(pthread_t *t, void *(*fn)(void *), void *arg)
{
    pthread_create(t,NULL,fn,arg);
    pthread_detach(*t);
}

void *threadfn(void *p)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i = NUM_THREADS;
    while (i-- > 0) {
        launch(t1 + i, threadfn, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** I have found that if you launch all threads *BEFORE* detaching any of them it appears to prevent the race condition from manifesting. See the following block of code which **does not** generate a race condition:

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 3

pthread_t t1[NUM_THREADS] = {0};

void launch(pthread_t *t, void *(*fn)(void *), void *arg)
{
    pthread_create(t,NULL,fn,arg);
}

void *threadfn(void *p)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        launch(t1 + i, threadfn, NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_detach(t1[i]);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

If you add another pthread_create() call after any of the pthread_detach() calls then the race condition re-appears. This leaves me feeling like it's impossible to use pthread_detach() and subsequently use pthread_create() without causing data races.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just restructured everything so I could join my threads, I really don't see how detached threads could work without causing this data race.